# Undefined control sequence error with moderncv

Tags: moderncv

When I use these commands to display a bibliography in a `moderncv` document I get an Undefined control sequence error.

```
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{publications}
```

This is the error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\ref@jnl #1->{\jnl@style 
                         #1}
l.17 \newblock {\em \mnras
                          }, 370:529--558, August 2006.
```

The `\mnras` macro is defined in a style file `aas_macros.sty` that is imported in the preamble. The exactly same commands work well when I use the article document class. What could be going on?

Comment: The code please!

Comment: It is going to be a bit difficult for people to figure this out unless you give them some relevant information. What's in the macros file, for example? Please give a Minimum (non-)Working Example people can play around with. This will enable people to help you more effectively.