# Moderncv and AAS macros lead to Undefined control sequence

Tags: moderncv, aastex

I am trying to use `moderncv` in conjunction with the `aas_macros.sty` (found at http://cdsads.u-strasbg.fr/abs_doc/aas_macros.sty). However, the following fails:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage{aas_macros}
\name{First}{Last}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

while the following

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,sans]{paper}
\usepackage{aas_macros}
%\name{First}{Last}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

works just fine. In both cases, the `test.bib` file contains

```
@ARTICLE{2015ApJ...806L..12O,
   author = {{Oishi}, J.~S. and {Mac Low}, M.-M. and {Collins}, D.~C. and {Tamura}, M.},
   title = "{Self-generated Turbulence in Magnetic Reconnection}",
   journal = {\apjl},
   archivePrefix = "arXiv",
   eprint = {1505.04653},
   primaryClass = "astro-ph.SR",
   keywords = {magnetic reconnection, turbulence},
   year = 2015,
   month = jun,
   volume = 806,
    eid = {L12},
   pages = {L12},
   doi = {10.1088/2041-8205/806/1/L12},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2015ApJ...806L..12O},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

Could anyone provide guidance on what is going on? Incidentally, this is a duplicate of [Undefined control sequence error with moderncv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154504/undefined-control-sequence-error-with-moderncv) but with a minimum failing case.

Thanks!

Comment: Two reasons: one, there are many other journal abbreviations in the full bib file I want to include in my CV. Two, the bibtex comes directly from the astrophysical data service, which I would like to continue to use, in this format. I'd really like to not have to manually update each future paper as it comes out. However, that would be a possible workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The AAS macros are part of the document class `aastex`.  So if you want to use these macros you should use this class and not `moderncv`.  Class `moderncv` does not know what `\def\apjl{\ref@jnl{ApJ}}` from your named `sty` files should do.

So in my eyes the best would be---if you insist in using this abreviation commands---to create an own abreviation file, for example `my-aas_macros.sty` and add there the renaming command.

For example:

```
\renewcommand{\apjl}{The Astophysical Journal Letters}
```

If you have abreviations please add them in a new line. Or copy lines 37 until line 101 of `ass_macros.sty` and change all of them as shown above (`\apjl` you find in line 41).

Now change your line `\usepackage{aas_macros}` to `\usepackage{my-aas_macros}`to use the bib file from the journal with their abreviations.

Comment: The problem is that `moderncv` does not support bibliographies in that way `article` does.  `moderncv` misses some commands which are included in standard class `article`.  `moderncv` is limited and that's the reason why I prepare a special bib file for my cv.  In my cv I need for example no field `note`, etc.